# Spring Tool Suite is removing plugins when laptop is restarted in Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos

I have downloaded STS in my Mac (Sierra 10.12.1) and installed the subclipse and jboss plugin but everytime I restart my laptop and start STS the plugins are removed, Did someone know what is happened?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

I just notice that the plugins are installed in Users/myUser/.p2/pool/plugins, if I run the  command `locate subclipse` it shows the location of the plugins but my eclipse is not finding them.

Comment: I'm too facing the same issue with Eclipse Neon.3 on Mac Sierra. Everytime i restart the laptop, all the installed plugins are getting deleted. I have to install all the plugins every single time I restart my laptop.

Comment: I decided to download the neon version of eclipse and not the STS, now the eclipse can find the path of the plugins, I think there is an error in the version of STS for mac, so one solution I think is to download the neon eclipse and download in eclipse neon the spring boot plugin

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: yes, it works for me